# Angular - Get Component name from a URL

Tags: angular

I have routes defined this way in `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'abc/:id', component: AbcComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'xyz/:id/tester/:mapId', component: XyzComponent
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/page-not-found', pathMatch: 'full'}
]
```

I would like to get the component name based on a URL in `app.component.ts`

Ex: If a user navigated to `http://myapp.com/abc/123` I would like to the get the component name, which in this case would be `AbcComponent`

If a user navigated to `http://myapp.com/xyz/123/tester/456` I would like to the get the component name, which in this case would be `XyzComponent`

How can I get that?

I tried to use ActivatedRoute, but it doesn't seem to work, as I get `Cannot read property 'component' of null`.

```
  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {
 this.checkRoute()
}

checkRoute()
{
   console.log(this.activatedRoute.routeConfig.component.name)
}
```

Comment: Haven't tried it - you can get the current url from the router and then do a filter on the `routes` array to find the corresponding component name. Will that do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

You could add the name of each component to [the data object](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route) of the accordant route, like:

```
{
  path: 'abc/:id',
  component: AbcComponent,
  data: {
    name: 'AbcComponent'
  }
}
```

And then getting its value like demonstrated [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters-in-the-activatedroute-service):

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.data.subscribe((data: { name: string }) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

**Edit:**

I have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-b8cwrr?file=app%2Fapp.routing.module.ts). Open the console and click on *Catalog*.

Comment: For some reason console.log(data) is giving me an empty object.

Comment: It appears that if you do this in a Child component, it works, but not in the app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Try this it work for me

```
constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {
 this.checkRoute()
}

checkRoute()
{
   var snapshot = route.snapshot;
   console.log(snapshot._routeConfig.component.name); 
}
```

Hope useful

Comment: It might work in child component, but it doesn't work inside app.component.ts